# Moved Joomla from subdirectory to root and suddenly get "Strict Standards" error...?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I upgraded from Joomla 1.5 to 2.3 and after moving it from a sub-directory to root, I could not access the administrator page (which previously worked fine). After logging in, I was presented with a blank page. I modified configuration.php, changing $error_reporting to maximum to try and track down the problem. Now, after logging in, I am presented with:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method LoginController::login() should
>   not be called statically in
>   /home/diamonde/public_html/administrator/components/com_login/admin.login.php
>   on line 21 Fatal error: Call to a member function login() on a
>   non-object in
>   /home/diamonde/public_html/administrator/components/com_login/admin.login.php
>   on line 64

I am baffled. Where do I even *begin* to resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Did the folder have a custom php.ini file that kept it on an older version of PHP?

Comment: What happens when you turn error reporting to default?

Comment: @Elin - No :\  Our only php.ini is in the /usr/local/lib directory.  We did update our php recently to accomodate some necessary elements of the newer version of Joomla, however.  (Though everything worked fine while it was in the subdirectory in our post-update testing.)

Comment: @Lodder - it is simply a blank page after entering administrative login information.

Comment: You updated PHP? To 5.4+ yes? In which case it's a simple php.ini or .htaccess file change. Quick Google search will do the trick ;)

Comment: 2.5 core won't generate any strict errors, but some extensions may.  It looks like you may have some 1.5 code somewhere.

Comment: @Elin - finally stumbled on the solution.  Thank you for trying to help though, it was much appreciated to have someone at least point me in a direction.  Elin, you were very close to right... I did have 1.5 code remnants hanging about--but not in extensions, just in loose files (specifically in the administrator/components/com_login dir)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION!!!!!!**

I had simply copied over my old Joomla 1.5 with my new 2.5 thinking it would over-write all files (and, well, it did).  HOWEVER, there were also old 1.5 files still hanging around which were causing problems.  I have no idea how or why—it doesn't make sense that the mere presence of unused files could cause issue—but nonetheless, that is the case.  Deleting the ENTIRE public_html directory FIRST, THEN copying in the new 2.5 fixed all my problems.

Hope this is helpful to someone who makes the same mistake!